# Print input strings combined in a continuous string

Tags: python, arguments

Can someone help me write an argument for cli so it can print the "input strings " as a combined continuous string?
How do I make this the real code to do what I want?

```
parser.add_argument('-c','--combine', action='store', dest='store_combined', help='Print input strings combined in a continuous string')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

so if I run $ `python HW3_cli.py -c` These Strings Get Concatenated then I get `TheseStringsGetConcatenated` as a print.

Can I also print the length of each string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the string in a quote:

```
python HW3_cli.py -c "These Strings Get Concatenated"
```

Then in your code you can split by space like this:

```
args = parser.parse_args() 
print(args.store_combined.split())
#['These', 'Strings', 'Get', 'Concatenated']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always ideal to pass strings under quotes(""), else it will be difficult to distinguish what is a parameter and what is a value

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='HW3_cli.py')
parser.add_argument('-c','--combine', action='store', dest='store_combined', help='Print input strings combined in a continuous string')
options = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)

print ''.join(options.store_combined.split())
print len(''.join(options.store_combined.split()))

python HW3_cli.py -c "These Strings Get Concatenated"

TheseStringsGetConcatenated
27
```

As asked in the comment section: If you wish to have the length output for individual string then do as below

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='HW3_cli.py')
parser.add_argument('-c','--combine', action='store', dest='store_combined', help='Print input strings combined in a continuous string')
options = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)

print ''.join(options.store_combined.split())
for i in options.store_combined.split():
    print len(i),

python HW3_cli.py -c "These Strings Get Concatenated"

TheseStringsGetConcatenated
5 7 3 12
```

Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: i get this error when i run it HW3_cli.py: error: unrecognized arguments:

Comment: i get this error when i run it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        HW3_cli.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Do you think thats the right dest to use ? I also will need to len of each input string. for example if this is my input string: **hut, jekish, everest**  then my len() would give me 3 6 7

Comment: Done the changes as asked. Also can you copy over the exact failure message

Comment: This is the error i get.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           print ''.join(options.store_combined.split())
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you not passing quotes in the parameter passed ?